# Sales Territory Mapping

Tags: software-recommendations, zip-codes

My company is interested in using GIS to create sales territories in the pharmaceutical industry. We currently use "alignment" software, but now we're looking for more commonly used and versatile GIS options.

Primarily, we would like the ability to combine zip codes, cities, or counties into territories, and easily drag and drop them into other territories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Greg Using ArcGIS with Network Analyst will support your analytical problems and it supports drag and drop from Excel, access to demographic data, and changing and merging territories. For your non GIS workforce you can use ArcGIS for Server with Portal.  That will allow them to use lightweight apps for data collection, creating maps or just navigation. Also, instead of running your own server you could do ArcGIS Online and setup an organizational account for your company.  Bottom line: its a big problem with many solutions.

Comment: Both ESRI and QGIS can do what you request.  Ie joining tables, calculating routes/distances, importing/exporting to Excel/Access, and creating maps.  I am not sure if QGIS has a tool for defining sales territories (though I could be wrong) and QGIS is sort of lacking in the map composing department, but QGIS is free whereas ESRI products are a little on the expensive side.

Comment: Thanks guys, these are helpful suggestions. We took a look at ESRI Business Analyst, but it's quite pricey and may not be much of an improvement over our current alignment software. I like the ArcGIS for Server with Portal and ArcGIS Online ideas, they may work for us. I'll look into QGIS further too, especially since it's free. We may purchase ArcGIS (ArcInfo) just because I've used that a lot and it's fairly inexpensive, and Maptitude and possibly MapInfo could also work too I think.

Comment: Our open source app ODL Studio does this - see http://www.opendoorlogistics.com/tutorials/tutorial-territory-design/territorium/ - (so free software). I know of a couple of companies in pharmacuticals who've used it for territory design.